# knockoutjsを使用してjsonデータをカテゴリ毎にまとめて表示する方法

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

javascript初心者です。

```
[{"Category":"A","Title":"△△△","Uri":"○○○"},{"Category":"A","Title":"□□□","Uri":"×××"},]

<div data-bind="foreach:$data">
    <dl data-bind="data:Category">
        <dt data-bind="text:Category"></dt>
        <dd>
            <a data-bind="attr:{href:Uri}"><span data-bind="text:Title">/span></a>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/data/somefile", function (data) {
            ko.applyBindings(data);
        })
    });
</script>
```

上記の場合、「Category」と「リンク」が交互に表示されてしまいます。  
Categoryのデータが同じ場合、そのカテゴリを「dl」でまとめて、データを「dd」でリスト表示したいのですが、可能でしょうか。  
可能であれば教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$indexとバインディング・コンテキストより、一つ前の値と比較しif文でdtを制御します。

http://kojs.sukobuto.com/docs/foreach-binding
http://kojs.sukobuto.com/docs/binding-context
$indexとバインディング・コンテキストの詳しい説明は上記参照。

また、サンプルを以下に記載します。

```js
var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
  var category = String.fromCharCode(65 + (i/5 || 0))
  
  data.push({
    Category: category,
    Title: category + '-' + (i%5 || 0)
  });
}

ko.applyBindings({data: data});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<dl data-bind="foreach:data">
  <!-- ko if:$index() === 0 || $parent.data[$index()-1].Category !== $data.Category -->
  <dt data-bind="text:Category"></dt>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <dd>
    <a>
        <span data-bind="text:Title"></span>
    </a>
   </dd>
</dl>
```